# Jetpack Compose how do i work with images when variable changes?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I use the composable function image. I need to use the specific image depending on the variable it gets.
it looks like the code underneath when hardcoded and this works for the specific image.

```
Image(
       painterResource(id = R.drawable.carrot),
       contentDescription = "carrot",
       )
```

The problem is i want it to work like the picture below where recipe.image changes depending on what it gets from the database.

```
Image(
       painterResource(id = recipe.image),
       contentDescription = "recipe.name",    
            )
```

Somehow it needs the exact path to the drawable that is saved localy.

What i have tried:
I've tried to upload R.drawable.carrot directly to the database as an Integer, it saves it as something like 2400440340, when this integer gets into the painterResource it crashes.
I've tried to save the "R.drawable.carrot" directly as a string into the database but that don't work either because the painter needs an integer.

The only suggestions i can find to this problem on this site is this answer from 11 years ago:

```
int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier(drawablename, "drawable", getPackageName());
imageview.setImageResource(drawableId);
```

I can't seem to find the functions getResources or the getIdentifier.

Comment: `getResources` is called on a `Context`, in Compose you can get it with `LocalContext.current`. Also this looks like evolution of your previous question - next time please don't remove it, and just edit it.

Comment: Thank you! Not used to using stacks, i got confused and accidentally deleted the post

Comment: No problem! You can un-delete it in such case, but now there's no need anymore as you have this one.

Answer (score 0):

> What i have tried: I've tried to upload R.drawable.carrot directly to the database as an Integer, it saves it as something like 2400440340, when this integer gets into the painterResource it crashes.

It crashes because this `Int` value in Resources is just a runtime reference, which means if you restart the app, the Resource, for example `R.drawable.carrot`, gets new referenced.
If you want another image in your `painterResource`, you have to change the value of `recipe.name` somewhere or you save your image binaries in the database (which is not very performant, I recommend not to do that).

You can load them over assets:
If you dont't have an assets folder, creat one in this location:
`app/src/main/assets/`

And then you can access it with a function like this:

```kotlin
    fun getImageFromAssets(imageName: String): Bitmap {
        val imageStream = assets.open(imageName)
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream)
        imageStream.close()
        return bitmap
    }
```

Android Studio will suggest you to "Inline" the variable but don't do that. If you Inline the `BitmapFactory` at the return point, you close the `Stream` before you decode it.

You can now simply call the name from the database like:

`val image: Bitmap = getImageFromAssets("imageName.jpg")`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you know what is best practice then? I have been thinking about making a list with all the images and then save the specific list number into the database. So for example list(carrot, potato, tomato) then i save 0 -> for carrot into the database. In the end i would call painterResource(id = list(recipe.image).
I think this would work but it doesn't look very pretty or scaleable.

Comment: You could try to put your images in the assets folder and load them with their filename. In this case you're able to save the image name as string. I'll update my post above to show what i mean.